# Facebook sharing is not working for some users

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to share the some details on facebook, it is working for some users but not working for all users, it gives the error of required publish permissions.

```
void shareEventDetailsOnFacebook() {

    try {
        if (Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "SAHRE_ON_FACEBOOK", "ON").equals("ON")) {

            Logger.logger(" FriendsDetailsActivity  ", "response =======" + Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().toString());
            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("message", "I have booked!" + "\n\nEvent:" + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_NAME", "-1") + "\nOn:" + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_DATE", "-1") + "," + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_TIME", "-1");
            params.putString("name", Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_NAME", "-1"));
            params.putString("picture", Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_IMAGE", "-1"));
            params.putString("link", "www.google.com");


            Logger.logger("message", "I have booked a night out!" + "\n\nEvent:" + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_NAME", "-1") + "\nOn:" + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_DATE", "-1") + "," + Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "EVENT_TIME", "-1")+"#nightup");
            facebookID = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < listFaceBookID.size(); i++) {
                facebookID = facebookID + listFaceBookID.get(i) + ",";
            }
            facebookID = removeCommaAtEndOfString(facebookID);

            Logger.logger("FacebookIds ==================== " + facebookID);
            params.putString("tags", facebookID);

            params.putString("place", Utilities.getDataFromPreferences(WhosGoingActivity.this, "PAGE_ID", "-1"));

            Logger.logger(" FriendsDetailsActivity permissions   ", "response =======" + Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().toString());
            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Logger.logger("  invite()  FriendsDetailsActivity invite()  ", "response =======" + response.toString());
                }
            });

            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Please hepl me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code for Facebook sharing, it will prompt user for publishing permission if not yet granted!

```
private void shareOnFacebook()
    {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if(session.isOpened())
        {
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

            if(! isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
            {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;

                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);

                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                return;

            }

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getString(R.string.please_wait));

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

            postParams.putString("name", "Cabit");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Ready when you are");
            postParams.putString("description", getString(R.string.sharing_text));
            postParams.putString("link", "http://s3technology.net/");
            postParams.putString("picture", "");

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response)
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    System.out.println("Response"+response);

                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                    System.out.println("response object:"+graphObject);

                    if(graphObject != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

                            Log.v("callback completed", ""+response.getGraphObject());

                            String postId = null;

                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");

                            Log.v("postId", postId);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) 
                        {
                            Log.i("shareOnFacebook", "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                        }

                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

                        if(error != null)
                        {
                            toastMessage.showToast(error.getErrorMessage());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            toastMessage.showToast("Shared on Facebook...");                    
                        }       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toastMessage.showToast(getString(R.string.connection_error));
                    }

                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask requestAsyncTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            requestAsyncTask.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            loginViaFacebook();
        }


    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset)
    {
        for(String string : subset)
        {
            if(! superset.contains(string))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.d("onSessionStateChanged", state.name());

        if(pendingPublishReauthorization && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED))
        {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

            shareOnFacebook();
        }

        if(state.equals(SessionState.OPENED))
        {
            shareOnFacebook();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {       
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Log.d("onACtivityResult", "Entered");
        }

    }
```